# Where are multisets used in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question

Outside of factorization (integers into primes, polynomials into irreducibles) where else are multisets naturally useful in mathematics?

[edit]

Deleting. If anybody wants me to stop, please say so now.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), for example.

Comment: Statistics, at least as far as the basics are concerned (mean, median, mode, etc.).